# Nativescript Add ScrollView through Code (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, android, layout, nativescript

Using Javascript with Nativescript and I am loading a page through code rather than XML.

I have it all working, however I want to add a ScrollView and then place a layout with in that.

How would I go about this?

I have tried:

```
var scroll = new ScrollView();
var stackLay = new StackLayout();

stackLay.addChild(stuff);
....


scroll.addChild(stackLay);
```

However, I get error "scroll.addChild is not a function"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`ScrollView` is not a layout but inherited from `ContentView`, therefore you can't add more than one child.

Try

```
scroll.content = stackLay;
```

Comment: That's the correct answer - As a note - when in doubt you could always check the API references for available methods & properties  https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_scroll_view_.scrollview#content